# jsonSchema nested attribute conditionally required

Tags: jsonschema

In jsonschema, how can we make some of the inner attributes required based on the field values present outside.

In the following example,

```
{
  "type" : "a/b/c",
  "args": {
    "propA1": "",
    "propA2": "",
    "propB1": "",
    "propC1": "",
    "propC2": "",
    "c1": "",
    "c2": "",
    "c3": ""
  }
}
```

`type` can be `a` or `b` or `c`. `args` is always required.

conditions are,

- `propA1`, `propA2` are required if type is `a`,
- `propB1` is required if type is `b` and,
- `propC1`, `propC2` are required if type is `c`.

`c1`, `c2` and `c3` are always required

What I have done so far is,

```
"properties": {
  "type": {"enum": ["a", "b", "c"]},
  "args": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "propA1": {"type":"string" },
      "propA2": {"type":"string" },
      "propB1": {"type":"string" },
      "propC1": {"type":"string" },
      "propC2": {"type":"string" },
      "c1": {"type":"string" },
      "c2": {"type":"string" },
      "c3": {"type":"string" }
    }
    "required": ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
  }
  "anyOf": [{
    "type": {"enum": ["a"]}
    // how to specify required for inner properties of args?
  }, {
    "type": {"enum": ["b"]}
  }, {
    "type": {"enum": ["c"]}
  }]
},
"required": ["type", "args"]
```

Here how can we specify required for inner properties without repeating common properties in each object of `anyOf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `"properties"` inside of the `"anyOf"` the same way you use it in the main schema.  So just put both `"type"` (with the appropriate single-value `"enum"` and then "args" with the appropriate `"required"` inside of it.  You do not need to repeat the other contents of `"args"`.  It should look like this (although I haven't tested it).

```
"properties": {
  "type": {"enum": ["a", "b", "c"]},
  "args": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "propA1": {"type":"string" },
      "propA2": {"type":"string" },
      "propB1": {"type":"string" },
      "propC1": {"type":"string" },
      "propC2": {"type":"string" },
      "c1": {"type":"string" },
      "c2": {"type":"string" },
      "c3": {"type":"string" }
    }
    "required": ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
  }
  "anyOf": [{
    "properties": {
      "type": {"enum": ["a"]},
      "args": {
        "required": ["propA1", "propA2"]
      }
    }
  }, {
    "properties": {
      "type": {"enum": ["b"]},
      "args": {
        "required": ["propB1"]
      }
    }
  }, {
    "properties": {
      "type": {"enum": ["c"]},
      "args": {
        "required": ["propC1", "propC2"]
      }
    }
  }]
},
"required": ["type", "args"]
```